# How to use async/await in a single function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am using google places api to get a list off cafes nearby. So,the api provides max 60 places but they are present in 3 different pages.To get the list of all 60 places, it provides tokens in the first and second page with the help of which we can access remaining places. I wrote a function that stores the place ids in an array.The places from first page is storing fine. But, in the first request i am accessing the token for the next page. The problem i am facing is, the request for second page is being called before assigning of the token.So, it results in an error. How can i make the reqeust for second page to wait until the token value is assigned?

```
const request= require('postman-request');
const nearbycafes = (latitude,longitude,callback) => {
var placeids=[];
let token;
let count=0;
const url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+latitude+','+longitude+'&radius=1500&type=cafe&key=xyz'
request({url: url, json: true},(error,response)=>{
    console.log('ssss');
    if(error){
        callback('Error connecting to the API',undefined)
    }
    
    else if(response.body.results.length==0){
        callback('No such address exist. Try something else',undefined)
    }
    else{
            let i=0;
            //for(i;i<response.body.results.length;i++){
                placeids.push(response.body.results[0].place_id) 
            //}  
            if(response.body.next_page_token){
                 token=response.body.next_page_token;
                 count++;
                 console.log(count);
            }  
        }
        callback(undefined,{
            placeids
        })

})
console.log(count);
// if(count===1){
//     const url2='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+latitude+','+longitude+'&radius=1500&type=cafe&key=xyz='+token+''
//     request({url: url2, json: true},(error,response)=>{
//         console.log('ssss2');
//         if(error){
//             callback('Error connecting to the API',undefined)
//         }
        
//         else if(response.body.results.length==0){
//             callback('No such address exist. Try something else',undefined)
//         }
//         else{
//                 let i=0;
//                 for(i;i<response.body.results.length;i++){
//                     placeids.push(response.body.results[i].place_id) 
//                 }    
//                 if(response.body.next_page_token){
//                     token=response.body.next_page_token;
//                     count++;
//                 }
//             }
//             callback(undefined,{
//                 placeids
//             })

//     })
// }

}

module.exports = nearbyhospitals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a recursive function to get all the pages sequentially:

```js
const request = require('postman-request')

function getPage (lat, long, token, cb) {
  const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${lat},${long}&radius=1500&type=cafe&key=xyz${token ? `&token=${token}` : ''}`
  request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      cb(new Error('Error connecting to the API'), undefined)
    } else if (response.body.results.length === 0) {
      cb(null, [])
    } else {
      if (response.body.next_page_token) {
        getPage(lat, long, response.body.next_page_token, (err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            return cb(err)
          }
          cb(undefined, res.concat(response.body.results))
        })
      } else {
        cb(undefined, response.body.results)
      }
    }
  })
}

function nearbycafes (latitude, longitude, callback) {
  getPage(latitude, longitude, undefined, callback)
}
module.exports = nearbycafes

// just to try
nearbycafes(43.834527, 13.258358, (err, res) => {
  console.log({ err, res })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot see the 'second' request in the code above. I assume the second request is being done in the 'callback' function. If you want to be sure that 'token' is not empty when 'callback' is executed, simply call the callback directly after assignment:

```
    else{
        let i=0;
        //for(i;i<response.body.results.length;i++){
            placeids.push(response.body.results[0].place_id) 
        //}  
        if(response.body.next_page_token){
             token=response.body.next_page_token;
             callback(undefined, { placeids: placeids });
             count++;
             console.log(count);
        }  
    }
```

It appears that the positive (I assume) 'callback' call is outside of the 'else' clause. You sure you got the braces correct?

Best approach, though, is to avoid such 'global' variables as token in this case. You could parametrize callback and pass the token via function call. The rule of thumb in such chained requests is as follows:

```
function A(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        //...
        success: function (result) {
            //...
            $.ajax({
                // ...
                success: function (result) {
                // ...
                }
            })
        }
    });
}
```